# Initializing a DateTimeInput (or DateTimePicker)

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I already search but didn't find what I need.

I have two DateTimeInput in a form (Employee Form). One is for date of birth and the other is for date of admission.

I want to make that the first one starts showing a date from 1940 but I can't get it. The property "MinDate" didn't help me because this property it's just a limit and what I want is to set a start date for the control to be shown when you display it.
The control starts showing the current date but it doesn't make sense if your date of birth is in 1990 so you have to "go back in time" trhough the control since 2016 to 1988 for example.

So, how can I initialize the datetimeinput in 01/01/1990, to make the selector of dates starts on it?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: `I don't want that the datetimeinput shows a date before you choose` thats not how it works - the premise is that the `.Value` is always a valid date in the Min Max range

Comment: I realize that it was showing a date 'cause I set it in the text property... but anyhow, i haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, the DateTimePicker control has extensive options for user input. So you can use the mouse to click to the header (e.g. 2010-2019) and navigate back by decades. Or use the keyboard (cursor up/down/right/left) and navigate e.g. up and down quickly inside the selected field day/month/year.

[image: Using the mouse to choose a date]

[image]

Some thoughts: You may not show the DateTimePicker and set `.Visible = False` first. Adding a ListBox with your preferred year period (from 1940 - now) the user is expected to select his date of birth from a long list and make a second step with dateTimePicker - not really a good idea when thinking about user experience.

Of course you can set MinDate, MaxDate and Value at runtime by code before form load event is fired. Or use ListBox events to set your default values before you show the DateTimePicker control.

Following code lets start the control with 1940-01-31 and user input is valid between 1940-01-01 and today (Now).

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    '//--- date of birth
    DateTimePicker1.MinDate = "1940/01/01"
    DateTimePicker1.MaxDate = Now
    DateTimePicker1.Value = "1940/01/31"

    '//--- date of admission
    DateTimePicker2.MinDate = "1940/01/01"
    DateTimePicker2.MaxDate = Now
    DateTimePicker2.Value = Now
  End Sub
```

[image]

But all depends on your needs and the periods you want e.g. MinDate = Now - 75 years, Maxdate = Now - 20 years

You have to decide whether you want to program the functionality by yourself or to use the DateTimePicker control.

Comment: I know how to navigate through this control, and i can choose a date too. My problem is that I can not make that: when I push the button to dropdown the list of dates it shows the current day, current month and current year. But what I want is that display shows a day and month from the 1940. Could you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: @Emily13 - I updated the code snippet in my answer - try it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks help-info.de.... This is not exactly what I'm trying to do but helps me to be a little closer of my object. P.S. I haven't answered 'cause I was out of town and didn't have Internet